# Custom Policy-Based Authorization in ASP.NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm using ASP.NET API with .NET Framework 4.7.1

And I'm looking for custom policy-based authorization. [This](https://aspnetcore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security/authorization/policies.html) document described custom policy-based authorization for .NET core, but how could I implement it for .NET framework?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Nuget package that backports the Policy-based authorization to .NET Framework 4.

You can use `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.Mvc` or `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.WebApi` package, depending on what you need. Both packages will bring you the same functionalities described in the document you linked.

E.g.:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.Infrastructure;
using System.IdentityModel.Claims;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Concep.Platform.WebApi.App_Start
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AbleToCreateUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Source:
https://vladimirgeorgiev.com/blog/policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-4/

Comment: This is ASP.NET Core. The OP is looking for the equivalent in ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: Please notice that in the answer I wrote "There is a Nuget package that backports the Policy-based authorization to .NET Framework 4". Plus, the link directs to a page explicitly stating that the article applies to .NET Framework.

Comment: Is there a way to check for a policy programmatically? I need it in a webforms aspx page