# How to use enums as parameter for policy-based authorization in ASP.NET MCV controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

I was trying to implement policy-based authorization on ASP.NET MVC 5 and I was able to make it work (with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797250/custom-policy-based-authorization-in-asp-net-framework)).

But I'd like to replace the magic strings like in the following example...

```
[PolicyAuthorize(Policy = "Admin")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

... with Enums somewhat like this:

```
[PolicyAuthorize(Policy.Admin & Policy.Owner)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I've read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8744910/18892979) that it can be done by creating a custom attribute with the following example but I just can't figure out how to implement it properly:

```
public class AuthorizeRoles : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRoles(params MyEnum[] roles)
    {
        ...
    }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That's the custom `ResourceAuthorizeAttribute` I made for that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class PolicyAuthorizeAttribute : Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authorization.Mvc.ResourceAuthorizeAttribute
{
    public Policy[] Policies { get; }

    public PolicyAuthorizeAttribute(params Policy[] policies)
    {

    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

My `Policy` Enum:

```
public enum Policy
{
    Admin = 1,
    Office = 2,
    Teacher = 3,
    Student = 4,
    Owner = 5
}
```

My `Startup` class wuth the policies:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.UseAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Policy.Admin.ToString(), policy => policy.RequireRole(Rolle.Admin.ToString()));
            options.AddPolicy(Policy.Office.ToString(), policy => policy.RequireRole(Rolle.Office.ToString()));
            options.AddPolicy(Policy.Teacher.ToString(), policy => policy.RequireRole(Rolle.Teacher.ToString()));
            options.AddPolicy(Policy.Student.ToString(), policy => policy.RequireRole(Rolle.Student.ToString()));
            // still working on the following policy
            //options.AddPolicy(Policy.Owner.ToString(), policy => policy);
        });
    }
}
```

I'd be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Change your enums to powers of 2  like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64.  This way and method will work.  You are ANDing 1 & 5 which results in garbage.

Comment: The accepted answer in the post you mentioned answers your question